# How are these notations to be read?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I came across the following notations in a Software book:

1) $ S(P_0 , ..., P_{n-1} ) $ = ...
2) $ P(i |a,b) =  $ ...

First, are these function notations or set notations? I'm assuming they are function notations.

Second, how are they to be read? Here are my guesses...
1) **S** is a function of variables $ P_0 , ..., P_n-1 $. Is this right?
2) I don't know how to read **P**. How is this to be read?

Comment: Could this be about (conditional) probabilities? What kind of software is that?

Comment: It is possible that the "P"s may refer to probabilities.

Comment: It is not possible to answer this without more context. E.g., what is the book? $P_n - 1$ good well be a typo for $P_{n-1}$.

Comment: OK, The book is "The C++ Programming Language" by Stroustrup.  The underlying topic is on Random Numbers.

Comment: @Rob, Actually, the typo alluded to by you was in fact a typo. I've fixed it.

Comment: I can confirm - having read further in the referenced book - that the "P"s in equation 2 are indeed probability density functions. Possibly, the "P"s in equation 1 are similar.